# Convert CAShapeLayer raidus to MKcircle radius taking into account of zoom factor

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, cashapelayer

converting the cAshapelayer radius to mkcircle radius conversion.

Since shapelayer is based on the actual view's vertices and mkcircle radius is based on the map zoom factor, what is the best approach to convert?

Answer (score 2):

One Of the approaches to convert radius of MKCircle to the view's and back is listed below:-

1> Convert the Center point(lat,long) of MKCircle to that of ViewController's view. It would be the center of CAShapeLayer to be drawn.

```
[mapView convertCoordinate:yourCoordinate toPointToView:self.view];
```

2>MKCircle takes the radius as distance on map which will be in meters for iOS. This Distance has to be translated to distance on UIViewController's view. Following steps may be followed to calculate the same.

a) Get the (Lat,Long) at the radius r meters from MKCircle using:-

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)calculateCoordinateForDistanceInKm:(double)distanceKM bearing:(double)bearing initialCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    if(!CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(coordinate) || !isValidDouble(distanceKM) || !isValidDouble(bearing))
        assert("The Inputs are not Valid");

    double angularDistance  = tan(distanceKM / 6371.0f);
    double bearingRad       = degreeToRad(bearing);
    double currentLat       = degreeToRad(coordinate.latitude);
    double currentLong      = degreeToRad(coordinate.longitude);

    double newLatitude      = asin((sin(currentLat) * cos(angularDistance))
                                   + (cos(currentLat) * sin(angularDistance) * cos(bearingRad)));
    double newLongitude     = currentLong + atan2(sin(bearingRad)
                                                  * sin(angularDistance) * cos(currentLat), cos(angularDistance) - (sin(currentLat) * sin(newLatitude)));
    // newLongitude should be in the range -180 to +180
    newLongitude           = fmod((newLongitude + 3*M_PI), (2*M_PI)) - M_PI;

    return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(RadToDegree(newLatitude), RadToDegree(newLongitude));
}

bool isValidDouble(double number)
{
    if(isnan(number) || isinf(number))
        return NO;
    return YES;
}

double degreeToRad(double degree)
{
    double radians  = (degree *  M_PI)/ 180.0f;
    return radians;
}

double RadToDegree(double rad)
{
    double degree   = (rad *  180.0f)/ M_PI;
    return degree;
}
```

b) Translate the new co-ordinate to that of `UIViewController`'s view as mentioned in step 1.

c) Find the Distance between these two points.

```
CGPoint pointOne = [mapView convertCoordinate:yourCoordinate toPointToView:self.view];
CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoordinate = [self calculateCoordinateForDistanceInKm:1.0f bearing:youtCurrentLocationObject.course initialCoordinate:youtCurrentLocationObject.coordinate];
CGPoint pointTwo = [mapView convertCoordinate:newCoordinate toPointToView:self.view];
NSNumber *radius = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:hypotf(pointOne.x - pointTwo.x, pointOne.y - pointTwo.y)];
```

3) Draw the CAShapeLayer based on the radius and the first point(center of circle).

4)Convert the CAShapeLayer points bak to a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`to draw a MKCircle(after some desired requirement of yours). The center point and radius is already known for the CAShapeLayer, so the center would be some`(x,y)` and a point on the locus equidistant from center would be `(x + radius, y)`.

Use following to convert view's points back to coordinate of `MKMapView`.

```
[mapView convertPoint:someCGPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapView]
```

Note:- Formula to calculate the coordinate at a distance D from another coordinate.

```
Formula:    φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )
    λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )
where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, θ is the bearing (clockwise from north), δ is the angular distance d/R; d being the distance travelled, R the earth’s radius.
```

Hope it answered your query.